# Dynamic resizing of elements & displaying inline

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, inline

I've been trying to analyse how this is done for the past few hours and just can't get it working.

Here's an example: http://vpthemes.com/preview/Modality/

If you go there, look at the 4 boxes under the text "CLEAN DESIGN & GREAT FUNCTIONALITY". If you resize your browser window, you'll notice that the boxes will go 2 side by side, and then if you go even smaller, they'll all go one under the other. The WHOLE website is like that; everything seems to resize perfectly depending on the size of the window.

How the HELL is that done? I've tried so many CSS styles it's boggling my mind.

Thanks!

Comment: its default. Because there is added media queries for responsive layout. ex:  50% width for medium and 100% for smaller layout so these block adjusting 4 on desktop 2 on middle and one on smaller screen

Answer (score 0):

As kumar said its done by media querys. You could take off the responsive css classes or overwrite it with '!important'

Comment: Oh...yeah I see what you guys mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) magic. You can configure each element in order to stay still, push right, left, etc. In the end, you have a layout that magically reorganize itself according to the size of the window and the configuration you've done. The mechanics of Bootstrap are partly in JS.

Amazing, isn't it?

But, wait. There will be a time at which you will be really pissed off of magic.

With `@media` rules and CSS3 possibilities, you can manage to reproduce Boostrap features in order to kill the magic with fire!

Comment: Hey thanks! Yeah it does appear that those layouts use something similar (or the same) as Bootstrap. They are Wordpress templates and apparently Wordpress has that built it. I got it working using the @media code for now. Thanks again, guys.

Comment: In fact I checked directly at the source code of their page for Bootstrap libraries and found them. So my first guess goes at them using it :)

Comment: @Sugarkryptonite Please choose an answer to mark this question as resolved.